# Convert text to object with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have text like this:

```
(1th) a
(2th) b
(3th) c
```

Can i convert this text to object like this with jquery?

```
[{"place":"1th","text":"a"},{},...]
```

I want this to process text with each() function.
Any other solution for text processing with javascript or jquery is appreciated.

Comment: Where are your tries? Show what you have tried so far (js code).

Comment: sorry, no try in code, just searched it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your string does *always* have exactly one entry per line:

```
var regex = /^\((.+?)\)\s*(.+?)$/i;
var result = text.split( "\n" ).map(function( str ) {
    var parsed = regex.exec( str );
    return {
        place: parsed[ 1 ],
        text: parsed[ 2 ]
    };
});

console.log( result );
// => [{ place: "1th", text: "a" }, ...]
```

As a bonus, this solution does not require jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, it basically turns the string into an array, and then casts it into an object.

```
var str = 'hello my name is slim shady.';
var arr = str.split(' ');
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj[i] = arr[i];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
var textArr = ["a","b","c"];
var newObjectArr = [];

$.each(textArr,function(index,obj){

   var single = { "place":(index+1)+"th", "text":obj };
   newObjectArr.push(single);

});

console.log(newObjectArr); // will hold objects
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way, I suppose:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=text/javascript src=script.js ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <list>
            (1th) a
            (2th) b
            (3th) c
        </list>
        <br>
        <output></output>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript (script.js):

```
window.onload = function() {
    list = document.getElementsByTagName("list")[0].innerHTML.trim().split('\n')
    for (i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
        list[i] = list[i].replace(/[()]/g, '').trim().split(' ')
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("output")[0].innerHTML = list
}
```

Output:

```
list = [[1th, a], [2th, b], [3th, c]]
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YTAGe/